Issues Removing Integers from a Container in Python-- Some use cases are giving the correct responses, others are not
For the code below, I am having some issues and am not entirely sure what is going wrong. The idea is to add integers, check if they exist, and be able to remove them, while appending to the proper value. The code is simple, and the ADD and EXIST seem to work without any hitches. When trying to implement the REMOVE functionality, I am getting mixed results.
def solution(queries):
  container = set()
  results = []
  for query in queries:
      operation, value = query
      if operation == "ADD":
          container.add(int(value))
          results.append("")
      elif operation == "REMOVE":
          removed_value = int(value)
          if removed_value in container:
              container.remove(removed_value)
              results.append("true")
          else:
              results.append("false")
      elif operation == "EXISTS":
          if int(value) in container:
              results.append("true")
          else:
              results.append("false")
  return results

So for the first list of queries I feed in, the results are properly matching the expected results:
queries:
[["ADD","2"], 
 ["ADD","3"], 
 ["ADD","9"], 
 ["REMOVE","10"], 
 ["REMOVE","5"], 
 ["REMOVE","5"], 
 ["REMOVE","9"], 
 ["REMOVE","2"], 
 ["REMOVE","2"], 
 ["REMOVE","9"], 
 ["EXISTS","10"], 
 ["EXISTS","2"], 
 ["EXISTS","3"], 
 ["EXISTS","9"], 
 ["ADD","10"], 
 ["EXISTS","10"]]

Output result: ["", "", "", "false", "false", "false", "true", "true", "false", "false", "false", "false", "true", "false", "", "true"]
However, when I try the next set of queries, I am getting some errors:
queries:
[["ADD","0"], 
 ["ADD","1"], 
 ["ADD","2"], 
 ["REMOVE","1"], 
 ["ADD","0"], 
 ["ADD","1"], 
 ["ADD","2"], 
 ["ADD","1"], 
 ["REMOVE","2"], 
 ["EXISTS","2"], 
 ["REMOVE","2"], 
 ["EXISTS","2"], 
 ["REMOVE","2"], 
 ["REMOVE","1"], 
 ["EXISTS","1"], 
 ["REMOVE","1"], 
 ["EXISTS","1"], 
 ["REMOVE","1"], 
 ["EXISTS","1"], 
 ["REMOVE","1"], 
 ["REMOVE","0"], 
 ["EXISTS","0"], 
 ["REMOVE","0"], 
 ["EXISTS","0"], 
 ["REMOVE","0"], 
 ["ADD","0"], 
 ["EXISTS","0"]]

Expected results: ["", "", "", "true", "", "", "", "", "true", "true", "true", "false", "false", "true", "true", "true", "false", "false", "false", "false", "true", "true", "true", "false", "false", "", "true"]
Actual Results: ["", "", "", "true", "", "", "", "", "true", "false", "false", "false", "false", "true", "false", "false", "false", "false", "false", "false", "true", "false", "false", "false", "false", "", "true"]
Could someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I don't want to continue learning from here until I'm 100% sure of my issue.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. It's not really clear what you need help with. Maybe you should start by comparing the expected and actual results and explaining to yourself why you expected that result. That can start you towards a more specific question. For more tips, see [ask], [mre], and How to step through Python code to help debug issues. See also Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?

You container is set() and sets cannot contain duplicates - you're adding two times 2, then remove 2 and expecting you have 2 in the set (which isn't true).
Change the container to list():
def solution(queries):
    container = list()  # <-- change set() to list()
    results = []
    for query in queries:
        operation, value = query
        if operation == "ADD":
            container.append(int(value))   # <-- .append() here instead of .add()
            results.append("")
        elif operation == "REMOVE":
            removed_value = int(value)
            if removed_value in container:
                container.remove(removed_value)
                results.append("true")
            else:
                results.append("false")
        elif operation == "EXISTS":
            if int(value) in container:
                results.append("true")
            else:
                results.append("false")
    return results


Ah! Thank you so much. I didn't even realize this was a thing. I will be more aware of this going forward!
